# How to typeset slanted dots in systems of equations?

Tags: math-mode

I try to write the backward substitution upper triangular system in latex

the format look like this

I try to write the code but it doesn't work correctly

```
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        &a_{1,1}x_{1}  + a_{1,2}x_{2} +\;.....+ a_{1},{n}X_{n} = b_{1}\\
               &  a_{2,2}x_{2} +\;.....+a_{2},{n}X_{n}  = b_{2}\\
      \end{split}
     \end{equation*}
```

[image]

please help what is wrong I try the `&` in another code in my project and it works. Why here doesn't it work correctly? :(

[image]

Comment: Very bad title!

Comment: ok i correct the title.

Comment: @constantinosgeorgiou, the title is still completely unspecific :) How about "How to typeset slanted dots in systems of equations"?

Comment: ok thank you for the sugestion .i think now is ok :)

Comment: @constantinosgeorgiou, sure! The more I thought about it, maybe even better would be something like "How to typeset systems of equations with vertical, horizontal and diagonal ellipses". But, I'll leave this one to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `array` based solution:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% so we don't need too many @{}
\newcommand{\LD}{\ldots}%
\newcommand{\DF}[1]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{\dotfill}}%
\newcommand{\DD}{\multicolumn{2}{r}{\ddots}}%
\newcommand{\VD}{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\vdots}}%
\begin{array}{*{5}{r>{{}}c<{{}}}l}
a_{1,1}x_1 &+& a_{1,2}x_2 &+& \DF{3}     &+& a_{1,n}x_n &=& b_1 \\[1ex]
           & & a_{2,2}x_2 &+& \DF{3}     &+& a_{2,n}x_n &=& b_2 \\
           & & \DD          &            & & && \VD     & & \VD \\
           & &            & & a_{i,i}x_i &+& \LD        &+& a_{i,n}x_n &=& b_i \\
           & &            & & \DD          & && \VD     & & \VD \\
           & &            & &            && & & a_{n,n}x_n &=& b_n
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for placing the `\ddots` in the columns with the `+` symbols.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an `array`-based solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman clone - optional
\usepackage{array}               % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}   % col. type for bin. and rel. operators
\newcommand\myddots{\multicolumn{1}{r}{\ddots}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{*{5}{cC}c}
a_{1,1}x_1 &+& a_{1,2}x_2 &+& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\dotfill} &+& a_{1,n}x_n &=& b_1 \\
&& a_{2,2}x_2 &+& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\dotfill} &+& a_{2,n}x_n &=& b_2 \\
&& \myddots  && && \phantom{a_{i,n}x_n} && \vdots && \vdots\\
&&&& a_{i,i}x_i &+& \dotfill &+& a_{i,n}x_n &=& b_i \\
&&&& \myddots &&&& \vdots && \vdots\\
&&&&&&&& a_{n,n}x_n &=& b_n
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the solution

```
     \[    
       \begin{array}{@{}*{7}{c@{}}}
        & a_{1,1}x_{1}  + a_{1,2}x_{2} +\;.....+ a_{1},{n}X_{n} = b_{1}\\
          & a_{2,2}x_{2} +\;.....+a_{2},{n}X_{n}  = b_{2}\\         
          \end{array}               
   \]
```

Comment: The ampersands have nothing to do in an `array` environment except to change column. Which layout are you trying to obtain?

Comment: i dont now  he dont work the space :(  what can i do? i try to type the characher & and the space is not work correctly

Comment: But x=what alignment do you want to get, exactly?

Comment: the array is correct? if i use & the space is on the picture at the first post.is not difficult i have the idea put i do not correct i dont now what can i do to sovle this

Comment: With your code, the equations will be centred in a single column. Is it what you want?

Comment: is ok but he said he dont work correct i want to solve ln first picture of my post

Answer (score 0):

An `alignedat`-based solution, with the help of `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 

\begin{document}

  \begin{equation*}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
   a_{1,1}x_{1} + a_{1,2}x_{2} & +{}&\cdots\cdots \cdots \cdots + a_{1,n}X_{n} & = b_{1}\\
         a_{2,2}x_{2} & +{} &\cdots\cdots \cdots\cdots +a_{2,n}X_{n} & = b_{2}\\[-1.5ex]
        &\ddots && \vdotswithin{=}\\[-1ex]
        & & a_{i, i}x_{i}\eqparbox{M}{${} + \dots + a_{i, n}X_{n} $} & = b_{i} \\[-1.5ex]
        & &\eqparbox{M}{\raisebox{1ex}{$\ddots $}} & \vdotswithin{=}\\[-2ex]
        & & a_{n, n}X_{n} & =b_{n}
  \end{alignedat}
 \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]